# Is data science only for substantive specialist?

Tags: data, career

Right now there is a lot of hype for data science. Everyone is learning it. There are lots of courses and boot camps being offered. Unlike software engineering, however, are data scientists required to have a specialization in a specific domain? For example, if you want to be a data scientist and like to work on topics in biology, would you need to know a lot about biology?

Comment: Data Science requires some basic specialisations. You need knowledge of computer science, mathematics specifically  statistics and a bit of calculus as well. Data scientists process and work upon data which comes from various branches such as biology, literature, CS etc.

Comment: The data sets will be different between different industries, sectors, etc.  Some data sets will be highly structured, some will be semi-structured, and some will be completely unstructured.  Also, the terminology/nomenclature will be different between different industries, of course.  The math, stats, computer science, will be exactly the same between different industries.